# Lógica (if,elif,else) com erro no python

Tags: python

Código:

```
def get_status(df3):
    if (str(df3['Forecast RELEX']).lower() == 'nan' and str(df3['Forecast']).lower() != 'nan'):
        return 'Subir'
    elif df3['Forecast'] > df3['Forecast RELEX']:
        return 'Subir'
    elif df3['Forecast'] == df3['Forecast RELEX']:
        return 'Não Subir'
    else:
        return 'Não Subir'
# criar coluna nova para "status"
df3['STATUS'] = df3.apply(lambda row: get_status(row), axis = 1)
df3.head(200)
```

Tenho o código acima, mas não está respeitando as regras de if, veja o resultado:

```
   Product   Location   Start_Date  End_Date    Forecast  Comment   Forecast RELEX  STATUS
0   90646164    0001    01/04/2021  30/04/2021  15         OPECOM   13,07          Subir
1   90646164    0001    01/04/2021  30/04/2021  10         OPECOM   13,07          Não Subir
2   90646150    0001    01/04/2021  30/04/2021  11         OPECOM   27,24          Não Subir
3   90646143    0001    01/04/2021  30/04/2021  12         OPECOM   5,87           Não Subir
```

Linha 4, index 3, pede para "Não Subir", mas o ['Forecast'] é maior, deveria retornar "Subir". Alguém consegue me ajudar onde to errando?
Veja que a linha 2 index 1, está correto, retornando "Não Subir".

Comment: A coluna Forecast Relex, contem números com virgula `(13,07)`, para ser valido o seu if teria que ser ponto `(13.07)` ao invés de virgulas

Comment: Provavelmente você está comparando duas **strings**, `'12'` e `'5,87'`, então nessa comparação o caractere `'5'` é maior que o `'1'`, retornando o segundo valor como maior.

Comment: Se eu transformar , para . da errado, com o seguinte erro: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Uma breve explicação

Um erro muito comum é usar o lambda chamando uma função e nesta função referenciar o dataframe todo, quando o ideal seria apenas referenciar a linha

Exemplo:

Para a chamada `df["nova coluna"] = df.apply(lambda x: minha_func(x), axis=1)`

O erro seria

```
def minha_func(row):
   if df["coluna"] > df["outra coluna"]:
       return "Maior"
   else:
       return "Menor ou igual"
```

Em um dataframe de 1000 rows, o script rodaria o `lambda` 1000 vezes chamando a função. A função por sua vez, rodaria no dataframe todo (x1000). Ou seja, o script teria uma iteração de 1000 x 1000... Ao invés de 1000 apenas.

O correto deveria ser

```
def minha_func(row):
   if row["coluna"] > row["outra coluna"]:
       return "Maior"
   else:
       return "Menor ou igual"
```

## Vamos agora às soluções

### Caso 1, usando apply

O dataframe é

```
>>> df
    Product  Location  Start_Date    End_Date  Forecast Comment Forecast RELEX
0  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        15  OPECOM          13,07
1  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        10  OPECOM          13,07
2  90646150         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        11  OPECOM          27,24
3  90646143         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        12  OPECOM           5,87
```

- Passo 1: transformar coluna `Forecast RELEX` em float

```
# Virgula para ponto
df["Forecast RELEX"] = df["Forecast RELEX"].str.replace(",", ".")

# Coluna para float
df["Forecast RELEX"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Forecast RELEX"], errors='coerce')
```

- Passo 2 (tudo no lambda)

```
df["Status"] = df.apply(lambda row: "Subir" if row["Forecast"] >= row["Forecast RELEX"] else "Nao Subir", axis=1)
```

- Passo 2 (usando função)  Obs: Veja que coloquei passo 2 de novo, ou seja ou usa o primeiro Passo 2 ou usa esse

```
def get_status(row):
    if row["Forecast"] >= row["Forecast RELEX"]:
        return "Subir"
    else:
        return "Nao Subir"

df["Status"] = df.apply(lambda row: get_status(row), axis=1)
```

O resultado será:

```
    Product  Location  Start_Date    End_Date  Forecast Comment  Forecast RELEX     Status
0  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        15  OPECOM           13.07      Subir
1  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        10  OPECOM           13.07  Nao Subir
2  90646150         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        11  OPECOM           27.24  Nao Subir
3  90646143         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        12  OPECOM            5.87      Subir
```

## Caso 2

- Passo 1: transformar coluna `Forecast RELEX` em float

Fazer o mesmo que descrito no `Caso 1` acima

- Passo 2: criar uma coluna `Status` com NaN

```
import numpy as np

df["Status"] = np.nan
```

- Passo 3: Lidar com Subir

```
df.loc[df["Forecast"] >= df["Forecast RELEX"], ["Status"]] = "Subir"
```

- Passo 4: Lidar com "nao subir"

Uma vez que `Subir` já foi inserido...

```
df["Status"].fillna("Nao subir", inplace=True)
```

**Nota** Embora o `Caso 2` tenha mais passos, ele é bem mais rápido de executar que o primeiro. Ou seja, em dataframes realmente grandes, opte pelo segundo caso.

O resultado é o mesmo

```
    Product  Location  Start_Date    End_Date  Forecast Comment  Forecast RELEX     Status
0  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        15  OPECOM           13.07      Subir
1  90646164         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        10  OPECOM           13.07  Nao subir
2  90646150         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        11  OPECOM           27.24  Nao subir
3  90646143         1  01/04/2021  30/04/2021        12  OPECOM            5.87      Subir
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente da seguinte forma, substituindo a virgula por ponto e transformando em float!

```
def get_status(df3):
    if (str(df3['Forecast RELEX']).lower() == 'nan' and str(df3['Forecast']).lower() != 'nan'):
        return 'Subir'
    elif float(df3['Forecast']) > float(df3['Forecast RELEX'].replace(',','.')):
        return 'Subir'
    elif float(df3['Forecast']) == float(df3['Forecast RELEX'].replace(',','.')):
        return 'Não Subir'
    else:
        return 'Não Subir'

# criar coluna nova para "status"
df3['STATUS'] = df3.apply(lambda row: get_status(row), axis = 1)
df3.head(200)
```

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Nesse caso é um erro de Indentação , indente o codigo e ira funcionar

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigada! Não tinha reparado que tava com um pequeno espaço a frente no if... :D

Comment: Por nada, que bom que deu certo!

Comment: @ZéReisM.Olliver,  eu adicionei trecho `def get_status(df3):`  que estava escondio e só apareceu depois que editei a pergunta.

Comment: Quando você usa o `lambda x: ......., axis=1` vc está passando a linha e não o dataframe. Evite usar o mesmo nome de variável do dataframe